# Sobolev embedding fails for $p=n$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, lp-spaces

As everyone knows, the Sobolev embedding fails fails for $n\ge 2$ if we assume $p=n$. The standard example is the function $u(x)=\log \log \bigl(1+\tfrac{1}{x}\bigr)$.
This function is obviously unbounded. But how can I quickly check that it is in $W^{1,1}(B(0,1))$? I started out calculating, but it gets quite messy, so I was wondering if there is a short way? Thanks!

Comment: The trick is to consider integrating over the shells $2^{-n-1} \leq |x| \leq 2^{-n}$. On these shells the integrand is essentially constant, so you can get an upper bound out of that. The upper bound is pretty sharp, too.

Comment: By the way, the use of this trick in the Fourier domain winds up giving you the Littlewood-Paley decomposition, which is useful for similar reasons.

Comment: @Ian that refers to showing that the function is in $L^n$ or its derivative? Could you give me a reference for your second comment?

Comment: It works for both. But you do just have to deal with the derivative, there's no working around it.